# Operational Error in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm running sqlite3 and I cannot, for the life of me work out what is going wrong in my code. Baring in mind that it doesn't crash when creating other tables that come before it in the database. Part of me suspects it may be a case of capitalisation somewhere on an SQL statement but it was working normally a few days ago.

**Create Table function**

```
def create_table(db_name,table_name,sql):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
        if len(result) == 1:
            response = input("The table {0} already exists, do you wish to recreate (y/n): ".format(table_name)) #option to recreate the database
            if response == 'y':
                keep_table = False
                print("The {0} table will be recreated - all existing data will be lost".format(table_name))
                cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
                db.commit()
            elif response == 'n':
                print("The existing table was kept")
            else:
                print("Incorrect input, please try again.") #validation measure
                if len(result) == 1:
                    response = input("The table {0} already exists, do you wish to recreate (y/n): ".format(table_name))
                    if response == 'y':
                        keep_table = False
                        print("The {0} table will be recreated - all existing data will be lost".format(table_name))
                        cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
                        db.commit()
        else:
            keep_table = False
        if not keep_table:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()
```

**Tables that are causing the problem?**

```
def create_customer_table():
sql = """create table Customer
         (CustomerID integer,
          FirstName text,
          LastName text,
          Street text,
          Town text,
          Postcode text,
          TelephoneNumber text,             
          EmailAddress text
          primary key(CustomerID))"""
create_table(db_name, "Customer", sql)
```

*ignore the fact it isn't indented, it is on my program.

```
def create_customer_order_table():
    sql = """create table CustomerOrder
             (OrderID integer,
              CustomerID integer,
              Date date,
              Time integer
              primary key(OrderID)
              foreign key(CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID))"""
    create_table(db_name, "CustomerOrder", sql)
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/X/Downloads/manage_table_March_2015.py", line 110, in <module>
    create_customer_table()
  File "/Users/X/Downloads/manage_table_March_2015.py", line 78, in create_customer_table
    create_table(db_name, "Customer", sql)
  File "/Users/X/Downloads/manage_table_March_2015.py", line 33, in create_table
    cursor.execute(sql)
ysqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: In `create table Customer`, you're missing a comma after `EmailAddress text`. In `create table CustomerOrder`, you're missing commas after `Time integer` and `primary key(OrderID)`.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I knew it was going to be something basic. After I normalised my database and added foreign keys I admittedly didn't think to include commas after the primary key line. Again, thanks!

Comment: No worries! It's the obvious ones that are often the hardest to find!